# ecto_fixtures, preload associations

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am attempting to use ecto_fixtures (https://github.com/DockYard/ecto_fixtures) while testing my Elixir/Phoenix application. The challenge I'm facing is that I need associations preloaded, but I don't have any control over the process of creating a model from the fixtures files. By the time I get the resulting model for a given fixture its associated models aren't loaded. I like them to be preloaded and ready for primetime.

Currently when I define my fixtures as such,

in file basic_models.exs:

```
basic_models model: MyApp.BasicModel, repo: MyApp.Repo do
  basic_model_one do
    name("A Fake Name")

    other_model(fixtures(:other_models).other_model.email)
  end
end
```

in file other_models.exs:

```
other_models model: MyApp.OtherModel, repo: MyApp.Repo do
  other_model do
    email("fake@email.com")
  end
end
```

Of course there's a tag above my test like so:

```
@tag fixtures: ["basic_models"]
test "a test", %{data: data} do 
  some code
end
```

Inside the test, `data.basic_models.basic_model_one.other_model` has the value `#Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :other_model is not loaded>`

I don't see any way to preload that association, and ideally it would be so that I'm not playing games to finesse the data of my fixture. Perhaps an option somewhere to preload associations.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to achieve this.

You can declare a fixture like:

```
def basic_model_fixture(attrs \\ %{}, preload \\ []) do
  assoc = %{other_model: other_model_fixture()}
  {:ok, basic_model} =
    attrs
    |> Enum.into(%{
      name: "some name",
      other_model_id: assoc.other_model.id
      })
    |> MyApp.BasicModel.create_basic_model()

  basic_model
  |> Map.merge(for p <- preload, assoc[p], into: %{}, do: {p, assoc[p]})

end
```

Using a second parameter `preload` you can choose which relation you want to preload.

Each keys inside the `preload` parameter will merge the associated key of `assoc` map to your final fixture (`basic_model`)

In your test files, you can add preload informations:

```
basic_model = basic_model_fixture(%{}, [:other_model])
```

---

To be synthetic, you can use this macro to have this behaviour.

```
defmodule MyApp.UtilFixture do
  defmacro merge_preload(origin, preload, assoc) do
    quote do
      unquote(origin) |>
        Map.merge(for p <- unquote(preload), unquote(assoc)[p], into: %{}, do: {p, unquote(assoc)[p]})
    end
  end
end
```

and use it in all your fixtures.

```
def basic_model_fixture(attrs \\ %{}, preload \\ []) do
  assoc = %{other_model: other_model_fixture()}
  {:ok, basic_model} =
    attrs
    |> Enum.into(%{
      name: "some name",
      other_model_id: assoc.other_model.id
      })
    |> MyApp.BasicModel.create_basic_model()

  MyApp.UtilFixture.merge_preload(basic_model, preload, assoc)

end
```